# Автоматическое заполнение строк

Tags: google-apps-script

возникла такая потребность, При заполнении трех строчек, в следующей должна фиксироваться дата.
Данный код фиксирует дату только если напишу в первую колонку что-нибудь, но когда я копирую и вставляю текст в три ничего не происходит. Просветите пожалуйста.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
    var idRow = e.range.getRow();
    if (idCol == 1 && sheet.getName() == 'NL-3B') {
        var Value = e.range.offset(1, 3).getValues(); // Смотрим что в ячейке с лева на 2
        if (Value == "") {

            var vartoday = getDate();
            var res = 'Резерв';
            var pok = 'МАГ';
            sheet.getRange(idRow, 5, 12).setValue(vartoday);
            sheet.getRange(idRow, 4, 12).setValue(res);
            sheet.getRange(idRow, 6, 12).setValue(pok);
        }
    }
}
// Returns YYYYMMDD-formatted date.
function getDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate());
    //return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
    return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, работа с триггером в нормальном режиме возможна только при вводе данных, не при использовании буфера обмена. Т.о. вы должны ввести данные с клавиатуры или аналогичного устройства.

Comment: Код довольно странный. Почему вы заполняете 12 строк вниз?

Comment: @contributorpw , Если вставляю в одну строку, то все ок, в три никак.
Насчет 12 строк исправил